# kendo ui dataviz chart aggregate includes data from wrong month

Tags: datetime, charts, kendo-ui, grouping, aggregate

I'm building a basic line chart in Kendo UI Dataviz and I'm having a problem with the aggregation method. The goal is to group my sales data by month and aggregate the Sum(Amount) which seems to work in my chart but I'm experiencing a bug that causes data from the first day of October to be included in the sum for September. Oct 2 shows in October but Oct 1 is included in September's total.

The data is:

10/1/2013 12:00:00 AM, 22964.5000

10/2/2013 12:00:00 AM, 6762.9400

```
Html.Kendo().Chart(Model)
    .Name("revenue")
    .Title("Revenue Activity by Month")
    .Legend(legend => legend
        .Position(ChartLegendPosition.Bottom)
    )
    .Series(series =>
            {
                series.Area(s => s.TotalRevenue, categoryExpression: model => model.Date).Aggregate(ChartSeriesAggregate.Sum).Name("Total Revenue").Color("#73c100");
                series.Line(s => s.RevenueSubscriber, categoryExpression: model => model.Date).Aggregate(ChartSeriesAggregate.Sum).Name("Subscriber Revenue");
                series.Line(s => s.RevenueNonSubscriber, categoryExpression: model => model.Date).Aggregate(ChartSeriesAggregate.Sum).Name("Non-Subscriber Revenue");
            })
    .CategoryAxis(axis => axis.Date()
        .BaseUnit(ChartAxisBaseUnit.Months)
    )
    .ValueAxis(axis => axis
        .Numeric("revenue")
        .Labels(labels => labels.Format("{0:C}"))
        .Line(line => line.Visible(false))
    )
    .Tooltip(tooltip => tooltip
        .Visible(true)
        .Format("{0:C}")
    )
```

What I receive is a chart with two points on the X Axis. The first point is Sept 2013 and includes $22,964. The second point is Oct 2013 and includes $6,762.

Comment: I'm having similar problem.

Comment: I spent quite a bit of time investigating and determined the framework contains some kind of logic that causes this behavior. I needed to move onto a different part of the project and plan to come back to it. I'll let you know what I find. Chris

Comment: Can you post a sample on http://trykendoui.telerik.com/ ?